# Errant "]>" appears at top of store page after installing GTspeed

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a really annoying issue.  GTspeed normally works fine, but of course tonight it decided to act up.  After installing and enabling all of the minification settings (css combining and minifying, javascript minifying, expires headers) I noticed at the top of the page this appears:

```
]>
```

That's it.  I looked into a couple posts, but I'm not getting any results.  When I turn off GTspeed's optimizations, the website goes back to bare bones display, no style sheets.

Using grep, I've found the offending string in the cache.

```
var/cache/mage--e/mage---0b0_LAYOUT_FRONTEND_STORE1_RWD_DEFAULT: <if> (lte IE 8) &amp; (!IEMobile)</if>
```

This matches the issue in the generated HTML source:

```
<!--[if <!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]>
```

The end there, that extra ]>, is what's doing it.  How to squash this bug?!

This appears at the top of every frontend page, not in admin pages.  The site operates normally, aside from these characters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a third party extension. Please contact the module vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a layout XML or phtml file that causes this.

Generally I'd start debuggen this by validating the modules layout XML, grepping through the template files of the module for those characters and grepping through the code of the module to see if I can find the source.

Once you know the source you can debug from there.

```
$ grep -Ri ']>' .
```

From the module code or template folder on commandline

Comment: Thank you!  I was grepping in the wrong place, for the wrong thing.  I went into the module's directory, executed your grep, and the very first result was the issue.  In the modules Block class it was adding this bracket in the minifying logic.  I modified the source to remove the ']>', and it no longer appears on top of the page.  Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to notify the module vendor about the issue :)

Comment: Thank you for responding rather than simply voting me off the island!  I'll be sure to pay it forward.

Comment: Signup on magestackday.com and Ill consider it even ;)

Comment: Deal!  Cool concept, glad to help.